# Giving values to a List from a Dictionary / Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

If i have a dictionary and a list:

```
dict = {"A":1, "B",:2, "C":3}
list = ['C', 'A', 'B']
```

How to get the output list of both combined:

```
output_list = ['3', '1', '2']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
d = {'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
l = ['C', 'A', 'B']

output_list = [d[e] for e in l]

print(output_list)
```

*Explanation:* for each element `e` in the list `l`, we lookup the corresponding value of the key `e` in the dictionary `d`.

This gives the output:

```
[3, 1, 2]
```

And if you wanted the output to be a list of strings, you would convert the numbers with [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str):

```
output_list = [str(d[e]) for e in l]
```

This gives the output:

```
['3', '1', '2']
```

(And the usual advice is not to use `dict`/`list` as variable names -- they are [builtins](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) already).

Answer (score 0):

```py
#rename 
input_dict = {"A":1, "B",:2, "C":3}
input_list = ['C', 'A', 'B']
out = [str(input_dict[_e]) for _e in input_list]
```

Comment: While this code-only answer may answer the question, it is better to include some essential parts of the answer verbally here along with the code. Code-only answers can become invalid if the syntax changes.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this type of code :

```
dict_ = {"A":1, "B":2, "C":3}
list_ = ['C', 'A', 'B']
for i in range(len(list_)) :
    output_list.append(dict_[list_[i]])
```